# Adding reaction if message contains certain content

Tags: discord, discord.py

I wanted to ask how do I make my bot react to a message if it contains something, for example:

if the message *contains* "Hi" the bot will react with :wave:.

so how do I do this? any help is appreciated, I am new to the forum so sorry if I made any mistakes. :)

Comment: I think you should begin with reading a tutorial, doing a bit more research yourself :). This is the first reply on Google, and in there you can find how to react to messages: https://realpython.com/how-to-make-a-discord-bot-python/

Comment: got it! I sincerely apologize :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if 'Hi' in message.content.split():
        await message.add_reaction("")
```

It will probably work

*if you use cogs :*

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self,message):
    if 'Hi' in message.content.split():
        await message.add_reaction("")
```

Comment: I wrote hello 0_0
Everytime the 'Hello' is deleted